# Change file permissions for the entire folder

Tags: permissions, files, directory

I am trying to change the file permissions for the entire directory. Presently all the files in the dir have the following permission,

`-rw-------`

And I wish to change it to,

`-rw-r--r--`

I know I need to use `chmod` but since I need to change it for the entire dir, is there a command that will change the permissions for the entire dir in a single go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean the *files* in the entire directory. In that case, use a wildcard (`*`) to apply it to all files:

`chmod go+r *`

or

`chmod 644 *`

Both do the same thing.

**EDIT:** As has been said in the comments, you need to do `chmod 755 SampleOutputs/` to have execute permissions on the container folder itself (to be able to `cd` into it). However, I'd leave out the `-R` option because it will make all the files inside the folder executable, as well.